# counting number of paths between elements in a matrix

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a code to count the number of paths available from (0,0) to (n-1,n-1) in a square matrix of order n. I have tried to implement a code using recursion but the code gives stackoverflow error. Can someone help me findout the correction needed in my code.
input contains number of test cases in first line.
for each test case follows a line with order of matrix
then n x n matrix follows as shown in sample input below the code
In a matrix 1 represents a block, a path can be traced only through 0s.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.lang.Math.*;



public class TestClass {

public static int ans,arr[][];



public static void main(String args[] )throws Exception{
    File file=new File("C:\\Users\\Mujeeb\\Desktop\\ii.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
                        FileInputStream(file), "ASCII"));
    int cases = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());

    for(int x=0; x<cases;x++){
        int n= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
        ans=0;
        arr=new int[n][n];
        for(int t1=0;t1<n;t1++){
            int t2=0;
            for(String s:br.readLine().split("\\s+")){
                arr[t1][t2]=Integer.valueOf(s);
                t2++;
            }

        }
        if(arr[0][0]==1 || arr[n-1][n-1]==1){
            System.out.println(ans);
        }else{
            if(arr[0][1]==0){
                findpath(0,1,0,0,n);
            }
            if(arr[1][0]==0){
                findpath(1,0,0,0,n);
            }
            System.out.println(ans);
        }


    } 
}

public static void findpath(int x,int y,int xp,int yp,int n){

    if(x==n-1 &&y==n-1){
        ans++;
    }
    else{

    if(x<n-1){
        if(arr[x+1][y]==0 && !((x+1==xp) && (y==yp))){

            findpath(x+1,y,x,y,n);
        }
    }

    if(x>0){
        if(arr[x-1][y]==0 && !((x-1==xp) && (y==yp))){

            findpath(x-1,y,x,y,n);
        }
    }

    if(y<n-1){
        if(arr[x][y+1]==0 && !((x==xp) && (y+1==yp))){

            findpath(x,y+1,x,y,n);
        }
    }

    if(y>0){
        if(arr[x][y-1]==0 && !((x==xp) && (y-1==yp))){

            findpath(x,y-1,x,y,n);
        }
    }

    }

}


}
```

sample input:

1
4
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0

Comment: What is a "path" in your task? What are 1s and what are 0s?

Comment: what is a path?  what is the first two lines (1,4)?

Comment: In a matrix 1 represents a block, a path can be traced only through 0s.
Sorry just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you to go back to a cell you've already visited.

Comment: when icheck for other cells like if(arr[x+1][y]==0 && !((x+1==xp) && (y==yp)))  The second condition in if statement  !((x+1==xp) && (y==yp)) is for checking previous

Comment: @ShamikRahmanKhan it's not enough: it doesn't prevent you to turn around endlessly.

Comment: but the condition seems to be fine

Comment: But you’re only checking back one spot, so your pointer could go in circles.

Comment: Great! Be sure to accept @MauricePerry 's answer then!